# Distribution of random variables with their sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given that $X_i$ are $i.i.d. \ \forall i \ni \  1\leq i \leq n $

Is it true that

if $T = \sum_iX_i$ then

$$f(x_1, x_2,....,x_n, T) = f(x_1, x_2,....,x_n) $$

if $f$ is normal, exponential or poisson?

Please see the following picture. I am confused about the jump in the last step.

[image]

Comment: You need to define $f$.  You have two appearances, one of which has $n$ arguments and the other has $n+1$ arguments.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, OK I did

Comment: If $T=\sum X_i$ then the random vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n,T)$ has no PDF.

Comment: 1. If you want to "answer" somebody (which presumably means, to address their objections), at least signal it in the comments thread, using @. 2. How is the content of the picture you added related to my (standard) objection? True, an intermediary step is nonrigorous (note the bizarre notation $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,T=t)$...) but, suitably qualified, the conclusion that $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n\mid T=t)=\frac{f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{f_T(t)}$$ is correct.

Comment: @Did -- I know but I can't post a picture in the comments section. I apologize.

Comment: But you can post comments, right?

Comment: @Did Could you elaborate some more on your fist comment?

Comment: Sure: random vectors with a PDF cannot take their values in a subset of measure zero, such as the hyperplane $t=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ in the present case.

Comment: @Did but the joint probability $P(X_1,X_2,...,X_n,T)=P(T|X_1,..,X_N)P(X_1)P(X_2)....P(X_n)$ is well defined, right?

Comment: Sure, except that the factor you denote $P(T\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ corresponds to no PDF since the distribution of $T$ conditionally on $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a Dirac mass at $X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

Comment: Ah, I see the whole point now, thank you! Although now I'm very confused by the question...